# Want To Install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 from Scratch In UEFI Mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, uefi, windows-10

I am new to ubuntu community.I have experimented a lot with windows now I want to try ubuntu. I have deleted everything on my HDD using Gparted.(yeah,i knw foolish of me).I have 750GB HDD on a Samsung Laptop with i3-2nd generation processor and 1 GB NVIDIA graphic cards. I have used gparted for deleting my partitons. Gparted shows a total of 700GB unallocated space.I want to dual boot my ubuntu and windows so that I have a option of selecting one of them while booting.I have my friend's laptop with me so i have all resources at my command.
Here is what I have done till now(and how I fail)

1)I have made a bootable USB using rufus(and selecting option GPT partition scheme for UEFI.)

2)I also made a windows 10 bootable USB(Like above).

3)I select UEFI enabled and legacy disabled in my BIOS.

4)I try to install ubuntu using USB ....but it is where problem starts It goes into infinite loop of blue and black screen and nothing helps except force shutdown.

5)Now I try to install Windows 10 using USB....same as above happen.

6)Now I change legacy and UEFI both to enable and to my surprise my Ubuntu USB works but I was struck with GRUB2 terminal and when I typed boot it shows 'Kernel not present ...blah...blah'

Note:Option of secure boot is not present in my BIOS as of now but I remember I saw it while upgrading from Windows 8.1 to 10(I don't knw how the hell It disappeared)

What I want to knw is how shuld I dual boot win 10 and ubuntu 15.04...what shuld I choose Legacy or UEFi...and what shuld I install first Ubuntu or Windows and what settings do I keep for my USBs in rufus.

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated(As I am kind of frustrated now googling and trying same things over and over again).
Plz forgive me for poor english and/or any mistakes.I am a newbie.:-)

Comment: There are some advantages to UEFI, but any system with UEFI hardware is more complex. I would check that secure boot is off. With nVidia you need nomodeset. Is this an Ultrabook with dual video? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Windows only boots in CSM/BIOS from MBR partitioned drives and only in UEFI from gpt partitioned drives. I would install Windows first. For both Windows & Ubuntu how you boot installer UEFI or BIOS is how it then installs.

Comment: @oldfred yes it's ultrabook with dual video....i am able to install win 10 and ubuntu ....but in legacy....i am still not able to dual boot however....it automatically boots in windows

Comment: If both are CSM/BIOS/Legacy then you need to install grub2's boot loader to MBR. Easiest with Boot-Repair or manually from Ubuntu live installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to dual boot windows and Ubuntu in UEFI mode is to

- First Install Windows so that While installing Ubuntu, grub can recognize windows.
- The other thing to keep in consideration is that the GPT partition is UEFI in bootable usb.(The easy way to make bootable usb is to use rufus).

Comment: And make sure that internal HDD has a GPT partitioning, too. Otherwise Windows might install in MBR mode and ruin your entire UEFI construct.